# Installing a driver's INF file?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, wifi-driver, inf

I've been fixing a friends computer which had all manner of things wrong with it, so I just wiped the whole thing and reinstalled Windows 7 (with the debugged service pack update).

Everything was fine but there was no driver for the wireless adapter, so I downloaded the driver from Samsung's site (it's a Samsung r530), installed it and now every time I try to connect to a wireless network I get a BSoD. I uninstalled the driver and there is no BSoD while doing anything else, so clearly it's a driver issue.

After some more searching I came across a site that had numerous drivers for Qualcomm Atheros devices (www.atheros.cz) and [I found this driver](http://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wireless-download.php?chipset=37&system=5). But all they give is the INF file.

How do I go about installing this INF file?

Alternately, does anyone know what else the issue could be?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, read too quickly. Have you tried downloading it again? Maybe your download was corrupt. Once you download the file, right-click it and click Unblock, and then try it. My instincts tell me that you should still use the one from that site, and then figure out the problem from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install it oppening:

1. Control Panel
2. System
3. Device Manager
4. Right-click on your Wifi device
5. Then click on Update Driver
6. Select on "seach driver on computer"
7. Then insert the path of your INF file
8. Click OK and Windows will install the driver for you.

Comment: Perfect, work's a treat. Cheers.

Comment: Nice, glad to help you. :D