# Can't manually install a driver (.inf)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, inf

I have an AOC monitor with Freesync and I'm trying to install the driver the driver that they provide (http://aoc-europe.com/fr/products/g2260vwq6#product-detail-accessoires)

It's a .inf file, I read many tutorials on how to install them (for example [Installing a driver's INF file?](https://superuser.com/questions/316206/installing-a-drivers-inf-file))

The problem I have is that I can not see the file (though I can see the directory that contains it) and when I enter the path manually it gives me an error saying "The specified path does not exist or can not be accessed"

Here's a gif demonstrating this : [http://i.imgur.com/OYiGmiM.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/OYiGmiM.gifv)

Comment: I've not installed that way, but I think the prompt is for a directory, not a file. The usual way to install a particular file is to choose choose the other option (choose a file on this machine) and subsequently click on "Have Disc" under the list of compatible drivers. You should then be able to browse to the `.inf` file you want. I've not done this on W7 for some time, so I'm not exactly sure of the precise texts, but I hope doesn't matter, since you are working in French.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the folder that contains the .inf file in the path rather than the path to the file itself as windows will be looking for the file within a folder so try this;

c:\users\tim\desktop\m

Kind Regards =)

Comment: sorry AFH didn't see your comment you are correct

Comment: Suprisingly this worked and I hadn't though of it at all, thank you ! Eventually though I get another error : http://i.imgur.com/6HC8YRP.png (Windows has detected that the driver is already up to date) Any tip on this ? :p

Comment: Hi there I don't have a freesync monitor personally, but I had a quick look into the technology and apparently all it needs to function are a freesync compatible monitor and gfx card plus the latest catalyst drivers for your card  ,it does not need a different monitor driver to the windows one.Have you tried downloading and installing the lastest catalyst drivers from AMD?